Replacing `\everypar` with a hook
This snippet uses \obeylines and \everypar to add a number at the start of paragraphs and and \hfill. How can I replace the everypar since it not recommended to be used any longer, now that we have hooks, with a /para/begin or similar hook?
   \documentclass{article}
    \def\fox{the quick fox jumped over the lazy dog.\par}
    \newcounter{step}
    \begin{document}
    \everypar{\stepcounter{step}\thestep\hfill}
    \AddToHook{/para/begin}[mypkg]{$\bullet\quad$}
    \fox
    \fox
    \obeylines
    Mademoiselle from Armentires, Parlez-vous,
    
    Mademoiselle from Armentires, Parlez-vous,
    
    Mademoiselle from Armentires,
    
    She hasn't been kissed for forty years.
    
    Hinky-dinky parlez-vous.
    \vspace*{10pt}
    Oh Mademoiselle from Armentires, Parlez-vous,
    Mademoiselle from Armentires, Parlez-vous,
    She got the palm and the croix de guerre,
    For washin' soldiers' underwear,
    
    Hinky-dinky parlez-vous.
    \everypar{}
    \RemoveFromHook{/para/begin}[mypkg]
    \centering World War I Army Song\par
    
    \end{document}



{para/begin} not {/para/begin}.

@cfr Oops thanks!

\everypar was never really recommended for use.  It was the only choice. at the time

@JohnKormylo  where was this stated?  There was no other method to access every paragraph! Even now the hook uses it behind the scenes.

The big caveat about \everypar is that \everypar{} is commonly used (see \@afterheading for example).

LaTeX doesn't warn you if you use a non-existent hook. para/begin works fine.
\documentclass{article}
\def\fox{the quick fox jumped over the lazy dog.\par}
\newcounter{step}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
  \AddToHook{para/begin}[mypkg]{\stepcounter{step}\thestep\hfill}
  \fox
  \fox
  \obeylines
  Mademoiselle from Armentires, Parlez-vous,
  
  Mademoiselle from Armentires, Parlez-vous,
  
  Mademoiselle from Armentires,
  
  She hasn't been kissed for forty years.
  
  Hinky-dinky parlez-vous.
  \vspace*{10pt}
  Oh Mademoiselle from Armentires, Parlez-vous,
  Mademoiselle from Armentires, Parlez-vous,
  She got the palm and the croix de guerre,
  For washin' soldiers' underwear,
  
  Hinky-dinky parlez-vous.
  \RemoveFromHook{para/begin}[mypkg]
  \centering World War I Army Song\par
  
\end{document}



@yannisl ?? ...
